# Aggregate Deduction Guide

Tags: c++, c++20, template-argument-deduction

The code snippet given in the documentation for [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), doesn't seem to be explained by the rules preceding it

```
template<class... Args>
struct B : std::tuple<Args...>, Args... {};
 
B b{std::tuple<std::any, std::string>{}, std::any{}};
// aggregate deduction candidate:
//   template<class... Args>
//   B<Args...> F(std::tuple<Args...>, Args...);
 
// type of b is deduced as B<std::any, std::string>
```

Why is this deduction guide implied?

I would've thought that the aggregate deduction guide would be such that `b` would be of type `B<std::tuple<std::any, std::string>, std::any>`.

Comment: `B` inherits `tuple`, so isn't the first argument just to initialize the base class?

Answer (score 1):

> In addition, if
>
> - `C` is defined and satisfies the requirements of an aggregate type with the assumption that any dependent base class has no virtual functions or virtual base classes,
> - there are no user-defined deduction guides for `C`, and
> - the variable is initialized from a non-empty list of initializers *arg1*, *arg2*, ..., *argn* (which may use designated initializer),
>
> an aggregate deduction candidate may be added.

These conditions are met, so there is an aggregate deduction candidate.

> Let `e`<sub>`i`</sub> be the (possibly recursive) aggregate element that would be initialized from `arg`<sub>`i`</sub>, where
>
> - brace elision is not considered for any aggregate element that has
>
>   - a dependent non-array type,
>   - an array type with a value-dependent bound, or
>   - an array type with a dependent array element type and `arg`<sub>`i`</sub> is a string literal
> - if `C` (or its element that is itself an aggregate) has a base that is a pack expansion:
>
>   - if the pack expansion is a trailing aggregate element, it is considered to match all remaining elements of the initializer list;
>   - otherwise, the pack is considered to be empty.

Here, `e`<sub>0</sub> is the element of the aggregate that would be initialized by the first expression in the braced-init-list, namely the base of type `std::tuple<Args...>`. Brace elision is not considered because that base has a dependent non-array type. Our type also has a base that is a pack expansion, `Args...`. Since this is in trailing position, it is considered to match all remaining elements of the initializer, namely the `std::any{}` element of the braced-init-list. Therefore `e`<sub>1</sub> is the base class `Args...`.

> - If there is no such `e`<sub>`i`</sub>, the aggregate deduction candidate is not added.
> - Otherwise, determine the parameter list `T`<sub>1</sub>, `T`<sub>2</sub>, ..., `T`<sub>`n`</sub> of the aggregate deduction candidate as follows:
>
>   - If `e`<sub>`i`</sub> is an array [...]
>   - If `e`<sub>`i`</sub> is an array [...]
>   - Otherwise, `T`<sub>`i`</sub> is the declared type of `e`<sub>`i`</sub>.
>   - If a pack was skipped because it is a non-trailing aggregate element, [...]
>   - If a pack is a trailing aggregate element, the trailing sequence of parameters corresponding to it is replaced by a single parameter of the form `T`<sub>`n`</sub>`...` .
>
> The aggregate deduction candidate is a fictional function template derived as above from a hypothetical constructor C(`T`<sub>1</sub>, `T`<sub>2</sub>, ..., `T`<sub>`n`</sub>).

So `T`<sub>0</sub> is just the declared type of `e`<sub>0</sub>, *i.e.*, `std::tuple<Args...>` and `T`<sub>1</sub> is the declared type of `e`<sub>1</sub>, *i.e.*, `Args...`. Not that it matters in this particular case, but if there were multiple `T`'s that matched with `e`<sub>1</sub>, all of them would be replaced by a single parameter pack. The resulting aggregate deduction candidate is `template <class... Args> auto B(T`<sub>0</sub>`, T`<sub>1</sub>`...) -> B<Args...>`, *i.e.*

```
template <class... Args>
auto B(std::tuple<Args...>, Args...) -> B<Args...>;
```

> During template argument deduction for the aggregate deduction candidate, the number of elements in a trailing parameter pack is only deduced from the number of remaining function arguments if it is not otherwise deduced.

In this case `Args` is deduced as `std::any, std::string` from the first element of the braced-init-list. Because `Args` is fully deduced here, the number of elements in `Args` is not deduced from the trailing sequence of function arguments; thus, the fact that there is only one remaining argument (namely `std::any{}`) instead of two does not cause deduction to fail.